# Django Celery with Johnny Cache tasks failing with weird errors

Tags: django, django-celery, django-johnny-cache

I am running Django 1.4.5, Celery 3.0.15, Django Celery 3.0.11, Johnny Cache 1.4.

The calls to ORM in celery tasks sometimes fail with weird errors like `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'"` or `<MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: ''<ExceptionInfo: ObjectDoesNotExist()>''. Reason: ''PicklingError("Can\'t pickle <class \'scsite.models.DoesNotExist\'>: attribute lookup scsite.models.DoesNotExist failed",)''.>`:

Here is a sample stack trace:

```
Task scsite.tasks.send_signup_email[aecf0561-65af-4d11-a3a0-63d88b7e1a70] raised exception: ValueError("invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'd'",)

Task scsite.tasks.send_signup_email[aecf0561-65af-4d11-a3a0-63d88b7e1a70] raised exception: ValueError("invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'd'",)

Stacktrace (most recent call last):

  File "celery/execute/trace.py", line 192, in trace_task
    R = I.handle_error_state(task, eager=eager)
  File "scsite/tasks.py", line 537, in send_signup_email
    email_html = email_template.render(Context(data))
  File "django/template/base.py", line 142, in render
    context.render_context.pop()
  File "django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "django/template/base.py", line 837, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "django/template/loader_tags.py", line 155, in render
    return self.render_template(self.template, context)
  File "django/template/loader_tags.py", line 137, in render_template
    output = template.render(context)
  File "django/template/base.py", line 142, in render
    context.render_context.pop()
  File "django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "django/template/base.py", line 837, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "django/template/defaulttags.py", line 192, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render(context))
  File "django/template/defaulttags.py", line 474, in render
    self.extra_context.iteritems()])
  File "django/template/base.py", line 584, in resolve
    obj = settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID
  File "django/template/base.py", line 721, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "django/template/base.py", line 781, in _resolve_lookup
    raise
  File "django/db/models/manager.py", line 119, in count
    return self.get_query_set().count()
  File "django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 461, in get_query_set
    return super(RelatedManager, self).get_query_set().using(db).filter(**self.core_filters)
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 624, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 642, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1250, in add_q
    can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
  File "django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1185, in add_filter
    connector)
  File "django/db/models/sql/where.py", line 69, in add
    value = obj.prepare(lookup_type, value)
  File "django/db/models/sql/where.py", line 320, in prepare
    return self.field.get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
  File "django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 310, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 537, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)




Task scsite.tasks.update_various_denorm_fields[edddb260-041d-4195-83d7-f2e731e5d1a5] raised exception: ValueError("invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'",)

Stacktrace (most recent call last):

  File "celery/task/trace.py", line 242, in trace_task
    R = I.handle_error_state(task, eager=eager)
  File "celery/task/trace.py", line 415, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "scsite/tasks.py", line 470, in update_various_denorm_fields
    Person.objects.update_question_counts()
  File "scsite/managers.py", line 715, in update_question_counts
    person.update_question_count_denorm()
  File "scsite/models.py", line 2712, in update_question_count_denorm
    self.question_count_denorm = self.questions.count()
  File "django/db/models/manager.py", line 119, in count
    return self.get_query_set().count()
  File "django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 567, in get_query_set
    return super(ManyRelatedManager, self).get_query_set().using(db)._next_is_sticky().filter(**self.core_filters)
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 624, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 642, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1250, in add_q
    can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
  File "django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1185, in add_filter
    connector)
  File "django/db/models/sql/where.py", line 69, in add
    value = obj.prepare(lookup_type, value)
  File "django/db/models/sql/where.py", line 320, in prepare
    return self.field.get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
  File "django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 310, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 537, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
```

I believe the error is not in my code, it looks like cache becomes corrupt for some reason, and something like the following happens:

- CustomModel with pk=123 is retrieved.
- It is passed on to Celery to process.
- For some reason, the pk of the Custom model becomes a character like 'a', 'd' instead of 123. Another call is made with `MyModel.objects.get(pk='a')` and it obviously fails.

Actually, revisiting the code for this, it seems I am not passing an object to Celery as I mentioned above, just running the following manager method from a simple celery task.

```
@task
def mytask():
   Person.objects.update_question_count()


class PersonManager(models.Manager):
   def update_question_counts(self): 
        persons = self.all() # 1
        for person in persons: 
           person.update_question_count_denorm() #3
```

My guess is the following: when Line 1 runs, persons is obtained from cache, but while processing line 3, the cache obtained in Line 1 becomes corrupt.

Comment: I don't think that sending model instances as task parameters is a good idea in general. Anyway I've done it some time ago and it works. Have you tried running your task w/o celery?

Comment: Sorry, my question is a bit confusing since there are various different (but probably related) problems. I am running calling that last function as a celerybeat task in this case, so the problem there doesn't seem to be the same as the other passing objects to Celery. The task runs without problems without celery and usually runs fine with celery, it happens occasionally.

Comment: @ustun Hi. I'm facing a similar problem. Have you figured out what went wrong in your case?

Comment: @Kate Hi, no, I haven't been able to figure it out. Are you running the same stack? (Johnny+Celery+Django)